# "TclError: image", while adding a image to a Label

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I have been stuck trying to add an image to my tkinter GUI and google does not seem to give answers. I understand that I should not use grid or pack gemoetry managers within the same master window, and I havent as far as I can tell but every attempt has resulted in either of the following error messages:

```
TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
```

or:

```
TclError: image "pyimage86" doesn't exist
```

Incidently everytime I rerun my code the "pyimage86" changes, every run increases the number by 1, for example 'pyimage86', 'pyimage87', etc etc.

The first error message is particularly confusing because I am using .grid to place my labelled image into the class but the error is saying otherwise? (example code is not in a class, I know)

I have tried different images and converted the original image into a .TIF, .JNP, .PNG, .GIF but none give a result. I have also removed the Alpha channel (apprantly that might have been an issue when using ImageTK.PhotoImage but it did not help). I have also converted the image into grasyscale as a last ditch attempt but no luck.

```
import tkinter as tk          
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk



root = tk.Tk()

image = Image.open("TemplateRack_GUI.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)       

label = tk.Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo 
label.grid(row=5, column=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TclError: image doesn't exist - Tkinter multi-windows python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53520057/tclerror-image-doesnt-exist-tkinter-multi-windows-python). Second you have to **keep a reference** to your image to prevent garbage collected.

Comment: Hi stovfl, I thought I have kept a reference with the following line - label.image = photo

Comment: *" I have kept a reference"*: Yes, your Questions code has, the linked dup doesn't.

Comment: Ahh, well I followed the answer from the possible duplicate post and I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You say that your program gives you sometimes:

TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside which already has slaves managed by pack.

and sometimes:

TclError: image "pyimage86" doesn't exist.

**I can't believe that!**

Furthermore you said "I understand that I should not use grid or pack gemoetry managers within the same class"

About which class are you talking?

Tkinter docs says: Never mix grid and pack in the same **master window**.
Please check your code again because you are using somewhere pack and grid.

Comment: Why would I lie? This seems confrontational