# trying to show an image in python using Tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I have been trying to show an image for a game but it doesn't show can i please have some help?

I've tried to download PIL but it doesn't work with python 3.

```
from tkinter import *
canvas = Canvas(width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
Logo = PhotoImage('photo.gif')
canvas.create_image(50, 10, image=Logo)
label = Label(image=Logo)
label.image = Logo 
label.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TclError: image doesn't exist - Tkinter multi-windows python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53521007/7414759).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3.6.4 with Pillow 5.2.0

You can use: **python -m pip install Pillow**

Here is an example of how to use PIL with tkinter

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()
img = Image.open("test.png")
tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
label =tk.Label(root, image=tk_image)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont tell `PhotoImage()` what the first argunent is, it will assume its the widget's name. To get it to load a file you have to explicitly tell it that it is a file:

```
Logo = PhotoImage(file='photo.gif')
```

Comment: it says it doesnt recognise file type